# a file can't be found by the program

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file in the same folder of the main class called edges, but when i run it, it said there is an error.

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:

What should i change for the program?

```
import graphs.arrayGraph;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

class underground 
{
static int N = 308;
static double [][] edges = new double [N][N];
static String [] stationNames = new String[N];

static ArrayList<String> convert (ArrayList<Integer> m)
{
    ArrayList<String> z = new ArrayList<String> ();
    for (Integer i:m) z.add(stationNames[i]);
    return z;
}

static HashSet<ArrayList<String>> convert (HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>> paths)
{
    HashSet <ArrayList <String>> k = new HashSet <ArrayList <String>> ();
    for (ArrayList <Integer> p:paths) k.add(convert(p));
    return k;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) for (int j=0; j<N; j++) edges[i][j]=0.0;

    URL url=    underground.class.getResource("edges");

    Scanner s = new Scanner (new FileReader(url.getPath()));
    String z = s.nextLine();
    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        z = s.nextLine();

        String[] results = z.split(",");
        edges[Integer.parseInt(results[0])] [Integer.parseInt(results[1])]= 1.0;
        edges[Integer.parseInt(results[1])] [Integer.parseInt(results[0])]= 1.0;
    }

    url=    underground.class.getResource("stations");
    s = new Scanner(new FileReader(url.getPath()));
    z = s.nextLine();
    while (s.hasNext())
    {
        z = s.nextLine();
        String[] results = z.split(",");
        stationNames[Integer.parseInt(results[0])] = results[3];
    }

    arrayGraph G = new arrayGraph (edges);
    System.out.println(convert(G.shortestPaths(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1]))));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the file extension too. Sometimes that may be a problem.

Try edges.txt or whatever the extension is.

Comment: OP did not ask about it, but that could be his/her problem. We never know. Neither do they :)

Comment: And it's a common problem that newbies often miss. That's why I 1+'d the answer.

Comment: I have tried to add ".txt" to each of the files and in the program but still the same error appears.

Comment: What is the extension of the file? Or does it have none?

Answer (score 0):

Pass an InputStream into the Scanner. Don't use a FileReader.

i.e., change this:

```
URL url=    underground.class.getResource("edges"); // are you sure the name is correct?

Scanner s = new Scanner (new FileReader(url.getPath()));
```

to this:

```
InputStream is = underground.class.getResourceAsStream("edges");
Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
```

Comment: I have changed but another part cause failure.
    url = underground.class.getResource("stations");
    s = new Scanner(new FileReader(url.getPath()));

incompatible types
cannot find symbol variable url

Comment: @user3400792: you haven't done what that I've recommended. Please re-read my recs above. Please ask for clarification if anything is confusing.

Comment: @user3400792: I see what you've done. You've taken my recommendations literally, but have ignored the concepts completely. You should be smart enough to apply the above recommendations to your stations file, no? Come on now, -- you should make the same changes there: use an InputStream.